# apt-get update: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages'

Tags: apt, arm, multiarch

I get the following architecture error when doing `apt-get update`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://linux-packages.resilio.com resilio-sync InRelease
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://linux-packages.resilio.com resilio-sync/non-free armhf Packages [476 B]
Ign http://linux-packages.resilio.com resilio-sync/non-free Translation-en
Fetched 476 B in 0s (651 B/s)                     
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why can't it fetch all the repositories' information?

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 model B with a ARMv7-A CPU.

Comment: How did you end up with a Raspbian system that tried to use `armel`?

Comment: @StephenKitt I guess it was with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armel` according to [these instructions](https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924-Installing-Sync-package-on-Linux) that I misread. I thought it might be use useful to share my solution because googling didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `armel` architecture [supports ARMv4 instruction set](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2013/01/31/armhf-versus-armel/). In the Raspberry Pi family, that is:

- Raspberry Pi 1 model A
- Raspberry Pi 1 model B
- Compute Module 1
- Raspberry Pi Zero

The `armhf` architecture supports ARMv7 instruction set. In the Raspberry Pi family, that is:

- Raspberry Pi 2
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Compute Module 2
- Compute Module 3

The `armel` architecture is not found in the raspbian repositories so you need to [remove it from your configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Configuring_architectures).

#### Remove all packages of that architecture before removing it

```
sudo apt-get purge ".*:armel"
```

#### Remove the architecture

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armel
```

#### Update again

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: In Raspbian, the `armhf` architecture is used for everything, including Pi 1. But it doesn't have the same definition as in Debian.

Comment: @StephenKitt I just wrote `armel` is not in raspbian repositories, feel free to edit the answer if you can make it more accurate

Comment: After 2h of googeling this fixed my problems.